# Automatically fetch and pull on Debian server

Tags: git, unix, automation, fetch

I have a Debian server and a git repo (Assembla).
What I would like to achieve is to have a function which automatically fetches any new revision and puts it in our 'test' host.

Meaning that if I push a new change on the repo, I should see it within a minute on the server running already.

Is that possible?

My server runs Debian 6 Squeeze

**UPDATE**: I would also like to be able to tell where a folder should be placed (e.g. /src should go into the root folder).

Comment: can you be more precise? :D Thanks

Comment: git has post receive hooks which are typically used for that, I would assume assembla has service hooks that allow you to pro-actively tell your server to update, rather than polling for updates. "I would also like to be able to tell where a folder should be placed (e.g. /src should go into the root folder)." <- no idea what that means.

Comment: Yeah, ok. I have a folder in my repo named 'src'. I would like its content to be extracted in a specific location and not into 'src/'

Comment: personally, I'm no clearer with your comment. In any case, edit the question - don't use comments to add information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$1
cd $dir
git pull
cd -
```

Cron task:

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/bash path_to_script somedir
```

Comment: `*/1 * * * *` is the same as `* * * * *`

Answer (score 1):

You could always set up a crontab which does an update every few minutes. Something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/git pull origin master
```

I'm sure there are better ways though. But this will run the git command every 5 minutes.

Note: I'm not familiar with the Git CLI syntax, so make sure you write that correctly.